# EWS Managed API- get image by given Email

Tags: c#, ews-managed-api

Is there a way to retrieve image of the contact by passing EmailID to EWS Managed API.

Answer (score 0):

here is how to do it in the official documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190905(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_EWSMA

Comment: That right. Although I personally didn't find out how to get the `itemId` of a contact.